# Elastic Beanstalk stuck for more than 12 hrs

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, update, elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I have an EB application that is stuck with this error: Failed Environment update activity. Reason: Internal Failure. I can not abort anything and I cannot change any configuration.. I dont know what to do, because every thing I do, it says: Could not abort the current environment operation for environment-xxxxxx: Environment named environment-xxxx is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be pending deployment.

I want to destroy the application or remove everything to start again, but I cannot do that.

Does anyone know how to unlock this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I decided to remove every DB, load balancer, security group, S3 bucket related to this environment.. I don't know if it is ok, but I'm quite desperate.. At least, it is not consuming anything (apparently)

Answer (score 38):

If you know how to fix the source of problem (for example: change application settings in Beanstalk Environment variables or deploy fixed version of your application), then:

1. Go to page [Auto Scaling Group](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/autoscaling/home?region=us-east-1#AutoScalingGroups:), choose your region, find Auto Scaling Group by Beanstalk Environment ID (like e-abcd12345).
2. In Details tab, push "edit", set Desired, Min and Max to 0. Remember previous settings.
3. In Beanstalk page, wait for message like "Removed instances [i-xxx, i-yyy] from your environment."
4. Change settings or deploy your application
5. Return Autoscaling settings back.
6. Be patient, it may took 5-10 minutes to change Beanstalk health to "Ok".

Comment: I had this happen in my production environment, so setting desired capacity to 0 wasn't an option. Instead I terminated the new instance created by the deployment from the Monitoring tab, and then I followed your directions but set min and desired capacity the pre-deployment values. After about 8 minutes, EB recovered from the stuck state like you said it would. Thank you!

Comment: The termination part is available in the Health tab.